# Right way to build a link in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Im trying to build a dynamic link with a view page (blade) with Laravel 5.3.

My approach is:

```
<a href=" {{ URL::to('articles') }}/{{ $article->id}}/edit">Edit></a>
```

that will output the right url with my base url and some other slug:      `http://mydomain/articles/23/edit`
Where "23" is my article's id.

This works but I wonder if there is a cleaner way to do that?

many thanks

Comment: isn't this cleaner?

Comment: `URL::to()` is the Laravel 4.2 available method. Since 5.0, you can use `url()`, along with any `Facade` classes like `URL`; they both do the same thing and are both clean approaches. I think you may be overthinking this relatively straightforward task.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [named routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#named-routes) for this

```
// Your route file
URL::get('articles/{articleId}/edit', 'ArticlesController@edit')->name('articles.edit');

//Your view
<a href="{{ URL::route('articles.edit', $article->id) }}">Edit</a>
```

Much more cleaner IMO

Comment: thanks it works! the route file was already filled ok by using the  `Route::resource('articles','ArticlesController');`
" method

Answer (score 2):

You can use named routes for cleaner in code

In your app/Http/routes.php (In case of laravel 5, laravel 5.1, laravel 5.2) or app/routes/web.php (In case of laravel 5.3)

> Define route

```
Route::get('articles/{id}/edit',[
             'as'   =>'articles.edit',
             'uses' =>'YourController@yourMethod'
            ]);
```

> In Your view page (blade) use

```
<a href="{{ route('articles.edit',$article->id) }}">Edit</a>
```

One benefits of using named routes is if you change the url of route in future then you don't need to change the href in view (in your case)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this

```
<a href="{{ url('/articles/edit',$article->id) }}"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-edit"></i></a>
```

and your **route.php** file

Route::get('/articles/edit/{art_id}', 'ArticlesController@edit');

Answer (score -1):

I recommend to work with named routes!

Your *routes/web.php* file:

```
Route::get('articles/{articleId}/edit', 'YourController@action')->name('article.edit');
```

Your Blade-Template file:

```
<a href=" {{ route('article.edit', ['articleId' => $article->id]) }}">Edit></a>
```

Comment: the minus is not mine...by the way i try your approach but it fails due the output that is equal to article.edit/id so not what im looking for

Comment: i forgot to put the name() on the route so maybe it fail due this problem

Comment: Yeah, my comment was addressed to the guy who downvoted my answer.

And like you said: you need to give the route a name to use the route() helper. If you don't have a name on the route you can use the url() helper instead.