# Class 'HTML' not found (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_demo\resources\views\pages\registration.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravelcollective

I am beginner in laravel 5.3 and i have added href link to my html form it's get an error like

> Class 'HTML' not found (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_demo\resources\views\pages\registration.blade.php)

I refer the following link for installing forms and Html

[Installation](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html)

**My View page**:

```
{{Form::open(array('action' => 'RegistrationController@store', 'method' => 'post'))}}
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
           Entr SNO:
        </td>
        <td>
         {!! Form::text('sno', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td>
          Enter Name:
        </td>
        <td>
         {!! Form::text('sname', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td>
          Enter Course:
        </td>
        <td>
         {!! Form::text('course', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td>
           Entr SNO:
        </td>
        <td>
       {{ Form::select('number', [1, 2, 3], null, ['class' => 'field']) }}
        </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
    {!! Form::submit('Submitform', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
            </td>
            <td>
               {{ HTML::link('http://test.com') }}
            </td>
    </tr>
</table>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Form is working well but when i add 'href' link is not working.Please help me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39639707/right-way-to-build-a-link-in-laravel-5-3 Heres a few answers, should help you out :)

Comment: @thanks Kray-But I know this I tried it .But after  i add link like {{ HTML::link('http://test.com') }} Then i get this error... . Am i anything wrong or this method is not possible?

Comment: Are you trying to create an INTERNAL (website) link, or are you trying to leave the application and direct the user to an outside link?

Comment: @Kray I tried to create an internal link

Comment: @Kray  <a href="/viewdetails">View Detials</a> i want to change the link like   {{ HTML::link('viewdetails') }} . i don't know i am doing right method or not?

Comment: `<a href="{{ URL::to('/viewDetails') }}">View Details</a>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131308/discussion-between-shanu-k-k-and-kray).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is with the capitalization of the class you're trying to use.

If you followed the instructions for the [`laravelcollective/html`](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html) package, you will have added this alias in your `config/app.php` file:

```
'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```

However, in your blade, you're attempting to use the facade as `HTML`. In your blade file, change your line to:

```
{{ Html::link('http://test.com') }}
```

Note: `Html::`, not `HTML::`.

Comment: thanks this is what i meant...but It shows whole url in view page

Answer (score 2):

You can try laravel :

> **URL::route('router_name','parameter_if_require')**

Do something like below for Example
Here have **single_post** route and it will take **id** so i can generate link some thing like below :

`<a href="{{ URL::route('single_post', $post->id) }}">View Post</a>`

For More check  [here](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#named-routes)

And If you want to use direct link then you can use

`<a href="{{ URL::to('/your_static_url') }}">Name</a>`

Comment: @thanks Binit Ghetiya But i need link like this {{ HTML::link('/viewdetails') }} Is this a wrong way?

Comment: @Shanukk can you please let me know in config/app.php => do you have this Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider registered ?

Comment: @Shanukk updated the answer you can use URL::to also try that.

Comment: One more doubt I have route

Comment: Route::resource('registration','RegistrationController');                                        Route::get('viewDetails','registration@viewDetails');    anything wrong?

Comment: @Shanukk if it is related to this question then ok else create new question and add in it. and mark this question answer correct if it worked for you thanks  :)

Comment: its related to question this is my route,anyway leave it thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131310/discussion-between-binit-ghetiya-and-shanu-k-k).

Answer (score 1):

Laravel is removing HTML ServiceProvider from built in packages in 5.3, either you install it with [LaravelCollectives](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html) or use helper functions.

Helper function like `url` or `routes`, here you have to write you own html.

```
<a href="{{url('Could be absolute or relative')}}">name</a>
```

You can read about more helper function here, [Laravel Helpers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-url).

Answer (score 0):

`<a href="{{'presentation_page'}}/{{$latest_file_uploads->id}}" class="title" title = "{{$latest_file_uploads->file_name}}" >`

try like this it will work great

Answer (score 0):

Its html package error...so install HTML package
     and then move  following steps.
process(1)

```
step(1) Go -> composer.json-> "require":{ .... "laravelcollective/html": "~5.0"

step(2) cmd
      C:\xampp\htdocs\any_project file> composer update
step(3) app.php-config
     add folloewing these statement.
     -> 'provider' => [ Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class, ]
     ->'aliases'   => [ 'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
                       'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,]
```

process(2)

step(1) `Go -> composer.json-> "require":{ .... "illuminate/html":"5.*"`

step(2)

```
cmd
          C:\xampp\htdocs\any_project file> composer update
    step(3) app.php-config
         add folloewing these statement.
         -> 'provider' => [ Illiminate\Html\HtmlSeviceProvider::class, ]
         ->'aliases'   => [ 'Html' => Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade::class,]
```