# Best way to route an anchor tag in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, anchor

I have a page that contains a list of tasks, I placed an anchor tag on each task which will take the user to : `/tasks/{{id}}`

This works: `<a href="/tasks/{{$task->id}}"><h4>{{$task->title}}</h4></a>`

**I was wondering if there are any better ways to approach this?**

This is what my controller looks like:

```
public function show($id) {
   $task = Task::find($id);
   return view('layouts.show')->with('task', $task);
}
```

My web.php file:

```
Route::resource('tasks', 'TasksController');
```

Comment: anchor tag means website/tasks#id-1 ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Right way to build a link in laravel 5.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39639707/right-way-to-build-a-link-in-laravel-5-3)

Comment: Those doens't look like anchor tags: `www.domain.com/home#the-anchor-tag`

Comment: Is there anything particular you don't like about this approach?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this approach, aside from maybe using `{{ url("/task/".$task->id) }}` or `{{ route("task", ...) }}` to ensure your have fully qualified URLs with the proper domain. And maybe some validation on your `show()` function so you don't get an error on `/task/not-a-task`.

Comment: How would my href look like with the `{{ route("task", ...) }}` approach?

Comment: Since you've defined the routes in the example using the `resource` method you would end up with something like `route('tasks.show', $id)`. If you haven't used the resource method then you will need to get your routes a name yourself. Then benefit to this is you can update the url for a route without having to update your links.

Comment: `<a href="{{ route("task", ["id" => $task->id]) }}">{{ $task->title }}</a>`, (syntax may be off; I don't usually use named routes) but I'm not sure how it plays with `Route::resource()`, since for `route()` to work, your Routes need a name, like `Route::get("/task/{id}, "Controller@show")->name("task");`

Comment: If you want to see what the route names are that have been set up then you can run `php artisan route:list` from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want hardcoded the url all the time, use `route name`

since you are using `Route::resource('tasks', 'TasksController');`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers#resource-controllers

`tasks.show` is route name

```
{{ route('tasks.show', $task) }}
```

so in some day, if you want change the uri of the route, just edit the web.php

and also you can use Route Model Binding

```
public function show(Task $task) {
   return view('layouts.show', compact('task'));
}
```

this command can help you make the controller and model

`php artisan make:controller TestController --resource --model=Models\Test`